# How should a mergetool indicate success of a merge?

Tags: git, exit-code, mergetool

I'm writing a program to be able to merge custom binary files. I want to let Git trust the exit code of my program, but it seems badly documented which exit codes do indicate a success.

The doc for [git-mergetool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool#Documentation/git-mergetool.txt--tlttoolgt) states:

> If the custom merge tool correctly indicates the success of a merge
>   resolution with its exit code, then the configuration variable
>   `mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode` can be set to `true`. Otherwise, git
>   mergetool will prompt the user to indicate the success of the
>   resolution after the custom tool has exited.

But this doesn't tell me which exit codes to use for which case.
Any ideas?

Comment: Probably by exiting with exit code 0. Typical standard for exit code meanings is that 0 is success, anything else is an error and usually the exact non-zero exit code means different types of errors. So I would return 0 if successful, 1 if not.

Comment: Usually exit code 0 means success, while any other indicates an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git follows the Unix/POSIX standard conventions: 0 = success, nonzero generally implies some kind of failure.

Often (but not in Git) 2 is used for improper-usage diagnostics and/or `--help` output; equally often, though, `--help` results in successful exit, and this is the case for Git.  (Meanwhile `git not-a-git-command` results in status 1.  That is, failure-that-produces-some-help results in exit 1, while a request *for* help produces exit 0, in Git.)

The `git bisect` command has one other special exit code, namely 125, that it interprets unusually when returned from a command invoked by `git bisect run`; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_run) for why 125 means what it does here.